# Production or Distribution?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

i try to find out whether my Application is running in production or in distribution mode.
I need this when I save the device information to the server.

How can I get from the IOS application whether the App runs in distribution or in production mode?

thx

EDIT:
I need to find out whether I need the distribution or production cert when sending a push notification to a device.
Therefore I save the appInformation and the deviceInformation (MAC-Adress,deviceTokenDistribution and deviceTokenProduction) to a database.
To send a push notification I need the information about what cert I have to use for the Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that whether your app running in the development mode or in the distribution mode? I think the production is the same mode with distribution.

You can add DEBUG=1 to your project's preprocessor symbol definitions in the Debug configuration's settings, then use #ifdef in your code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"It's development mode");
#endif
```

Comment: i mean e.g. when I use Push Notifications. I want to know if i need the Distribution or the Production for sending a push notification

Comment: Send push notification depends on your APN server certificate matching with app's. Both Distribution and development can send push notification.